# Unable to sign out using gapi.auth.signOut

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client

I am integrating Google Social login in my web app (AngularJS). I am not able to sign out the user.
Below is my slightly simplified approach -

Scenario 1. First time user -

I have my own button, which when clicked loads page 'X'. This page redirects user to Google login and/or App permission approval page.
Finally X returns user back to my site. I am passed info that I am logged in through Google and now I have to sign in through gapi so that I can sign out later.

sign in can be implemented in 2 ways -

1. `gapi.auth.authorize()` with `immediate: true` OR
2. `gapi.auth.signIn()` with `'immediate': true`

I have tried both. Neither works. Second has a additional disadvantage that browser shows that a popup has been blocked.

Then there is a sign out button, which calls `gapi.auth.signOut()` and loads page 'Y'. 
Page Y returns back to my site, and the scenario 2 is triggered (read below), which loads up signed in page :(

Scenario 2. Returning user, in same browser.

Using below code, first I check if there is google acess_token, so I can attempt to login through Google.

```
gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: self.googleAppId,
    immediate: true,
    scope: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'],
    cookie_policy: window.location.protocol+'//'+window.location.hostname
}, function (response: any) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.access_token) {
        self.googleLogin(response.access_token);
    }
    else {
        self.loadHome();
    }
});
```

The googleLogin loads another page 'Z', which redirects back to my original page.
The Z passes me parameters in URL, so that I know I have logged in through Google. And I go back to scenario 1.

The issue is - if user has signed out using `gapi.auth.signOut`, then why is `gapi.auth.authorize` (in scenario 2) returning a access_token?
How can I at second scenario distinguish between a signed in and signed out user?

I tried replacing `gapi.auth.authorize` with `gapi.auth.signIn()` in second scenario.
But this loads up google log in page as soon as my index page is loaded. So I didn't explore it further.

Please let me know where am I going wrong and how to fix this.